# Metonymy of curtain

Tags: figurative-language, metonymy

> Immediately, **the heavy velvet folds hid** the stage from the
>   audience, Farrar was up on her feet, and she and Caruso were having it
>   out between them, whilst I tried.

I am wondering if we can replace "folds" with curtain here without a change of meaning. Is it a metonymy and can we really substitute "curtain" with "folds" in any narrative text (creative fiction)?

Comment: You could replace _folds_ with _curtain_ here, but the meaning of _folds_ is dependent on context. It might refer to a woman's voluminous skirts, a cloak, or a length of uncut fabric, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a metonymy. You are replacing the word with one of its attributes.

You can do this *provided you give enough context* for the reader to know what you are talking about.

If you say

> I just bought some new folds.

There is no way that anyone will understand you.  But in the example given, we are told that "folds" refers to something that is heavy and velvet, that is found at the theatre, and hides the stage from the audience.  It is pretty clear, even if that word were to be erased, what the meaning is.

So metonymy occurs in two ways, standard idiomatic expressions like "suit" to mean the business person (these tend to be slang words).  And creative metonymy, where the author invents their own new expression, as in the example you give.